# Odoo 12 Menu not Showing in Module

Tags: xml, odoo-12

I'm currently building a module, and I can make a parent menu that is shown on the home screen, however when I attempt to add a sub menu inside the module nothing is showing up.

I've been trying to rename the root menu, the sub menu, rebuilding the menu item, the action record.

Here is my root menu:

```
<menuitem id="menu_product_return_root"
      name="RMA Management"
      web_icon="jvmf_rma_management,static/images/rma.png"
      action="action_product_return"
      groups="group_product_return"
      />
```

and here is my sub menu:

```
<menuitem id="menu_rma_global_settings"
      name="Settings"
      parent="menu_product_return_root"
      action="action_rma_configuration"/>
```

When I look at other examples that already exist in the code the sub menu should show.  However nothing shows in the menu section of the page.

Comment: I figured this out and the menu now shows.

Comment: Well if you figured it out, you could add the solution actually!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In truth, I didn't put enough information in my original question.

```
<record id="action_rma_configuration" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Settings</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="res_model">res.config.settings</field>
  <field name="view_mode">form</field>
  <field name="target">inline</field>
  <field name="context">{'module' : 'product_return'}</field>
</record>

<menuitem id="menu_rma_global_settings"
  name="Settings"
  parent="menu_product_return_root"
  action="action_rma_configuration"
  groups="group_product_return"/>
```

I had to make sure that both the menuitem and the action record were built correctly.